# append to existing values if condition is true

Tags: excel

I want to compare the values row by row from sheet1-colors with sheet2-darkcolors

if they are both matching append the row values d and e to the fruits column in sheet 1

basically
`sheet1 colors |blue |=== sheet2 darkcolors |blue| ----> fruits+yummy+yuicy`

sheet1

| colors | fruits |
| --- | --- |
| blue | bananay |
| red | apple |
| green | kiwi |

sheet2

| darkcolors | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- |
| blue | yummy | juicy |
| black | tummy | fruicy |
| green | tummy | goosy |

result

| colors | fruits |
| --- | --- |
| blue | banana+yummy+juicy |
| red | apple |
| green | kiwi+tummy+goosy |

I tried using `IF` combined with `XLOOKUP` but could not get it running together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try-

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("+",TRUE,B2,INDEX(TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!$B$2:$C$4),,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A2:A4,0))),B2)
```

[image]